# What is pandorable?

Tags: python, pandas

I have [seen](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjBkd3C0Z3WAhVMsBQKHfZ1DVQQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.coursera.org%2Flearn%2Fpython-data-analysis%2Flecture%2FLn156%2Fpandas-idioms&usg=AFQjCNHKDkwSCZabMMM42aghkOrMrQKhsw) the term `pandorable` but I cannot find any accurate definition for that. What does that mean?

Comment: Citation, please.

Comment: @Emre [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjBkd3C0Z3WAhVMsBQKHfZ1DVQQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.coursera.org%2Flearn%2Fpython-data-analysis%2Flecture%2FLn156%2Fpandas-idioms&usg=AFQjCNHKDkwSCZabMMM42aghkOrMrQKhsw) you are

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a neologism for "fitting for pandas"; compare with "[pythonic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25011078/what-does-pythonic-mean)". As stated in the [lecture transcript](https://www.coursera.org/learn/python-data-analysis/lecture/Ln156/pandas-idioms):

> A sort of sub-language within Python, Pandas has its own set of idioms. We've alluded to some of these already, such as using vectorization whenever possible, and not using iterative loops if you don't need to. Several developers and users within the Panda's community have used the term **pandorable** for these idioms.

Comment: you are using professor's exact words? actually I have heard them, I needed some extra description. I searched alot but did not find anything useful. Any, thanks :D

Comment: Search the transcript. It's not a term I've ever heard before; it is not important.

Answer (score 2):

A more pythonic (or pandorable) way to change a list of columns to different data types

Comment: this can be a comment too..

Comment: Anyway, wlcome to community :)

Answer (score 1):

I've taken Chris Brooks' course, "[Introduction to Data Science in Python](https://www.coursera.org/learn/python-data-analysis)" on Coursera, too.  As he said in the "[Pandas Idioms](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/python-data-analysis/pandas-idioms-Ln156)" video you mentioned (and in its transcript quoted in other answers to this question), "pandorable" describes a style of coding with Pandas that uses features like method chaining, `applymap` (Pandas' version of Python's `map`), `lambda`, and other techniques.

My problem with calling those "pandorable" is that they are already elements of "Pythonic" style.  It doesn't make any sense to call these techniques by another name just because Pandas is involved.  That's "***pandeplorable***"! (™ pending).  Maybe there are elements of Pandas style I've not seen yet that merit the use of a new term, but so far it all looks Pythonic to me.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I also like the word *Numpaic* or maybe *Numporable* or such funny fancy things :)